# SSH to Remote Server and execute tar -zcvf remote directory and backup

Tags: ssh, tar

I am attempting to execute tar -zcvf  on remote using ssh back the file tar.gz to remote server.

example:- ssh gaxgpoa163vd | "tar -zcvf /oraapp/backup/test/test.log  /oraapp/backup/test.tar.gz" but couldnt make it success.

I am developing python script and above login implemented in the class make_tarfile.

```
def make_tarfile(fName,eNamei):
    print fName
    if eNamei == 'EAP':
            os.system('tar -zcvf '+fName)
    elif eNamei == 'QA':
            os.system('ssh gaxgpoa163vd | tar -zcvf /oraapp/backup/test/test.log > /oraapp/backup/test.tar.gz')
```

error:-
/oraapp/backup/PRODUCT_gaxgpoa162vd_26-September-2016-15:00:19.tar.gz /oraapp/product/fmw/
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or`tar --usage' for more information.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

stty: standard input: Invalid argument

PS:- using same user for login local machine and ssh to remote.

Regards,
TJ.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. Are you trying to run this command interactively? Or is this part of something which you're developing? Could you [edit] your question to include any relevant source code and include the error messages that you're getting, or describe how your attempts are failing?

Comment: @Kenster Please see edited the question and provided the logic that using my python script. Class "make_tarfile" called to back up the server files.

Answer (score 0):

after change os.system('ssh gaxgpoa163vd | tar -zcvf /oraapp/backup/test/test.log > /oraapp/backup/test.tar.gz') to os.system('ssh gaxgpoa163vd tar -zcvf /oraapp/backup/test/test.log /oraapp/backup/test.tar.gz') solved the issue.

Thanks for everyone who watched the thread.

Regards,
TJ